# Remove names from returned val()

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following script returns the name and text from inputs and drop downs and adds them to a text area. I need to remove the names (of each input/drop downs) from each of the values returned but I'm having no luck? the = have already been removed.

```
<script>
$('#formt').find('select,input[type="text"]').not('#tagt').change(function(){
    var val = "";
    var tags = '';
    $('form select,input[type="text"]:not("input#tagt")').each(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value).length > 0 ) {
          val += ($(this).attr('name') + "" + this.value + "");
        }  
    })
    $('#tagt').val(tags+val);
});

$('#submit').click(function(){
    window.location= $('#tagt').val();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Seeing your (relevant) HTML here would be a help, but if you don't want the `name` why are you retrieving it in the first place?

Comment: It's just a simple form with a couple of drop downs and inputs...nothing fancy.

Comment: So you wrote code that collects the name of each element, and now you want it to not collect those names? Do you understand the code you wrote?

Comment: I'm a complete novice with js...I found this script elsewhere and whatever I try (to remove the names) seems to stop it working completely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just remove the part where it gets the name, as in `$(this).attr('name')`

```
$('#formt').find('select,input[type="text"]').not('#tagt').change(function(){
    var val = "";
    $('form select,input[type="text"]:not("input#tagt")').each(function(){
           val += this.value;
     })
    $('#tagt').val(val);
});
```